# Op-Amp settling time in bits

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, timing

[image]

I was reading through this and was a bit confused. What do they mean by 
"took forever to settle to 10-bits (0.1%)"?

**How is 10-bits = 0.1%**

Comment: beware of that last  sentence "Thermal effects .... may cause precision settling to be milliseconds". The thermal timeconstant of 1 cubic meter is 11,400 seconds. The thermal timeconstant of 100 cubic microns (which is about the size of the input differential-pair transistors of older opamps), is ratio-squared faster, at 10^8 faster, at around 114 microSeconds. The entire package also stores heat, and can extend the thermal setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 10-bit binary number can take on 2<sup>10</sup> = 1024 values.

Therefore, if you want something to settle "within 10 bits," you're saying that it needs to settle to within 1 part in 1024: \$\frac{1}{1024} = 0.0009766\$, or 0.1% in round numbers.

Comment: Ah. That makes much more sense. THANK YOU!